# How do I remove a VirtualBox host only network adapter

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox, osx-yosemite

On OS X, 10.10, if I start a Vagrant based VirtualBox VM that is configured with a host only network adapter and then destroy that VM and attempt to re-create it with the VMware provider the vboxnet# adapter I used previously is still holding onto the static IP I have declared in the Vagrantfile. (the # at the end of vboxnet is an integer that can vary based on how many VM's have been spun up)

Without rebooting or uninstalling VirtualBox, how do I remove that vboxnet# virtual adapter?   It doesn't get presented in the OS X network properties window.

Comment: By the way, uninstalling VirtualBox and Vagrant won't clean the list. So, the solutions below are the way to go. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Open Virtualbox, click File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Network, remove Vboxnet#

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is just a simple and working way to do it on Win7. You helped me, thanks.

Comment: Sure enough, that looks like it would work.  (Not sure how I missed that back when I originally posted the question; did they add this to the GUI between then and now?)

Comment: Even it worked in Fedora too

Comment: This is now at `File -> Host Network Manager`

Comment: FYI, this showed nothing on my Mac running High Sierra.

Answer (score 38):

Looks like the VBoxManage command line tool is how to do it.  Couldn't find a way to do it from the GUI, but this seems to work:

`VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet4`

(replace the '4' accordingly, of course)

Comment: See above comment on how to do it via the GUI

Comment: This woirked for me on my Mac (High Sierra). In addition, you can list the networks with `VBoxManage list hostonlyifs`.

Comment: @EricSmalling It's possible that the GUI doesn't show a network, in which case this answer is more helpful